# Primality of a number of more than 50k digits

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, computational-number-theory

With modern tecnology is it possible to prove the primality of a number of more than 50k digits?

Obviously not a prime for which specific methods for testing primality are known like Mersenne primes.

Comment: A Google search returned http://www.ellipsa.eu/public/primo/primo.html, which as of 2 years ago, in the last update, worked up to 50,000 digits. See also https://www.google.com/search?q=primality+testing+large+numbers+site:math.stackexchange.com

Comment: "possible", yes, for any number of digits that fits your machine, if you are patient enough. The question is a bit vague - we would expect you have read the literature on primality tests. So why "50k"? What do you know about the question already?

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich The number 50k might come from the fact that primo currently has (if I understand correctly) a hard-coded limit of 50k digits.

Answer (score 23):

Yes, it is possible, but it is close to the boundary of what is reasonable. See for instance [this software](https://www.multiprecision.org/cm/) that was recently used by Andreas Enge to prove the primality of $10^{50000}+65859$. It took 100 days of real time and 71 years of CPU time. The certificate can be verified in 4 hours with 128 cores.

Comment: Can this be done much faster probabilistically, say with probability 1-2^(-100)? Is there a range of digits (maybe 100,000-digits or million-digit numbers?) where rigorous proofs is completely out of reach but probabilistic proofs can be done fast on usual PC?

Comment: @BogdanGrechuk Yes, there are much faster probabilistic algorithms, for instance the Rabin-Miller test, to name only one. The whole difficulty here is to obtain a proof (and even an efficiently verifiable certificate).

Comment: @BogdanGrechuk For instance the Pari/GP function `ispseudoprime` implements a version of the BPSW primality test, for which infinitely many pseudoprimes (composites that pass the test) are conjectured to exist but none is known. On the above example, it terminates in 15 minutes on a single core.

Comment: The record on 50001 digits (from June) was beaten in September by a 57125-digit prime. Also proved with Enge's CM software. See [PrimePages Top Twenty: Elliptic Curve Primality Proof](https://primes.utm.edu/top20/page.php?id=27).

Comment: If you take "Rabin-Miller test with 100 rounds" then it is most likely that there are an infinite number of pseudoprimes exist, but none will ever be known. Over three quarters would be identified as composite if. you ran 101 rounds of the test.

Comment: @BogdanGrechuk Huge numbers can be proven prime if we know the complete factorisation of p-1 and p+1 (or even just many factors). For Fermat primes, p+1 has a trivial factorisation. I think there are known 80 million digit Fermat primes. With 80 million digits, a "trivial" test suddenly becomes very time consuming :-( For general numbers in the same range with no particular properties, Rabin-Miller should be about the same order of magnitude for a probabilistic test.

Comment: @Aurel What is the estimated probability that a pseudoprime is in fact prime? Does it change as the number gets bigger?